# Putting a GWT widget into an expanded row

Tags: java, gwt

I would like to be able to put widgets into the GWT 2.5 expandable table's expanded part. To be clear: I have seen the showcase here: http://showcase2.jlabanca-testing.appspot.com/#!CwCustomDataGrid and saw that when I'm doing an expanded row I can override this method:

```
private void buildContactRow(ContactInfo rowValue, int absRowIndex,
    CellTableBuilder.Utility<ContactInfo> utility, boolean isFriend);
```

This looks like a very low-level method. This example shows how to work with TR's and TD's:

```
TableRowBuilder row = utility.startRow();
TableCellBuilder td = row.startTD();
```

I would like to place widgets into my expanded row. Do you have any idea how to do it? I thought of rendering a `<div id="foobar"/>` into the cell and getting this div from the DOM and putting a widget inside, but I'm afraid of that a div inside a widget (the table) cannot be used this way.

**Update:**

As you can see the question is not bound to the (still unreleased GWT 2.5). In general I'm looking for a solution for bindig a widget into a Cell being just rendered at the lowest level, e.g. DOM being built as String.

Comment: where did you get the 2.5 framework? is it an official release, or when is the offical release data? (I'm sure you have a nice link for it, please tell me :))

Comment: svn checkout http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ trunk

Comment: Actually I haven't worked with 2.5 I only have the linked showcase and the demo's sources. I'm not 100% sure that the trunk checkout is 2.4 or 2.5..

Comment: Thanks anyway. But this looks pretty alpha or beta like... so until there is no release of GWT 2.5 I'm afraid nobody can/ will help you. Also the implementation might change to the final release (unlikly because they already made the showcase but still possible) So in case you are not haveing to meet a deadline, I'd wait for the official release :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My final solution was implementing a `VerticalPanel` based table, where each row is a `HorizontalPanel`. This looks like a table, but is very easy to change the row widget to an `ExpandablePanel` with any content in it. As I do not need to handle huge data sizes (because I use paging) this solution was very quick. I made its API similar to GWT `CellTable` so it was easy to use.